# Xcode only shows the launch storyboard, and does not show the rest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to run a simple app with a search bar that displays the results. I have been following different tutorials but I can never get the app to get past the launch screen. I am new to swift and any help is appreciated!

viewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    let animals = ["cat","dog","fish","monkey","turtle","zebra fish"]
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func tableView(in tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(in tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)-> Int {
        return animals.count
    }
}
```

If I have the func tableView outside of the class it gives an error that animals is not defined.

Comment: Well, one problem is that you are declaring your types wrong. `numberOfRowsInSection` is not a UITableViewDelegate method. It is a UITableViewDataSource method. And `cellForRowAt` is a UITableViewDataSource method too. If you don't declare your types correctly, those methods will never be called and you'll never see anything in the table view.

Comment: Another problem is that you are declaring your methods wrong. For example, you are saying ` func tableView(in tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> UITableViewCell`. Well, that is not the correct declaration for the data source method. If you don't declare the method name correctly, it won't be called and you'll never see anything in the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your general settings make sure you set the main storyboard.
If you don't want that, in your AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you need to create a viewcontroller, add it to the window, and call makeKey on it.

If you are getting a compliation error: "animals" not defined, then define it in the scope of the viewcontroller.